# Docker Desktop 4.1 Windows - Won't start - Keeps showing "Docker Engine Starting"

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop

Tried some tips from other posts, and reinstalled a few times, but nothing has worked.

`%LOCALAPPDATA%/Docker/log.txt` keeps printing repeatedly:

```
[21:12:21.206][IPCClient         ][Info   ] (25ce5082) dbcce01c-WslIntegrationService-CSharp C->S WSLCrossDistroService GET /check
[21:12:21.208][LinuxWSL2Engine   ][Info   ] msg="(25ce5082) fdbefe10-cross-distro S<-C dbcce01c-WslIntegrationService-CSharp GET /check[[STACK]]   at Docker.Engines.WslIntegrationService.<WaitForDistroReadyAsync>d__18.MoveNext() in C:\\workspaces\\master-merge\\src\\github.com\\docker\\pinata\\win\\src\\Docker.Engines\\WslIntegrationService.cs:line 0\n"
[21:12:21.208][LinuxWSL2Engine   ][Error  ] msg="(25ce5082) fdbefe10-cross-distro S->C dbcce01c-WslIntegrationService-CSharp GET /check (102.8▒s): can't access specified distro mount service: stat /run/guest-services/distro-services/ubuntu-20.04.sock: no such file or directory[[STACK]]main.StartCrossDistroServer.func2({0xc0cf20, 0xc000354c40})\n\t/go/src/github.com/docker/pinata/linuxkit/pkg/wsl-bootstrap/cross-distro-service.go:58 +0x412\n"
```

Guess it probably happened after the most recent update, wondering if anyone has run into a similar problem?

Comment: Try to reset it to factory settings and then restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely to be a bug of 4.1.0.0, I have reverted to 4.0.1.0, and it is working now.

[Docker Desktop doesn't start after upgrade to 4.1.0](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12229)